# Dealing with links in html and css

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

There is a problem that i can't solve.
I am trying to make button from text by changing it on hover. I am using css to change their font color or background color on hover. There is no problem to this point.

But when i give them a link `<a href="www.twitter.com">` I have a problem because at this point my css doesn't work because of html's link hover and visited functions.

The big problem is **visited** .. i don't want the visited color to work. If visited color works, my links doesn't look like good.

If you can help me about links in texts (making hover) without problem of active section...

Thanks

Comment: Add some HTML and CSS please, if you feel like being nice even put it in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: To get rid of `:visited` styles, wherever you style your `a` element, add the `:visited` selector too: `a, a:visited { styles }`

Comment: Although I think Doctus is on the right track, can you please show us your HTML code where your links are, and the relative CSS code?

Comment: Thanks for answers ..a:link { color:red; }
a:hover { color:white; }
a:visited { ....... }

i want my text red to white when my cursor is over the text..
But if i had clicked the text before my text always become purple..

i dont want **the visited part of linking ..**

That is the problem ..

Comment: No one's given you an answer yet, it's still hard to provide an answer without you providing yuor markup so we can see how it's being used. What I usually do is make the visited color the same as the link color.

Comment: One tip: I think you'd want <a href="http://www.twitter.com">
Because if you don't add http:// then it will go to [yoursite].com/www.twitter.com

Answer (score 0):

By giving the link ("a") the css propertie text-decoration:none; the element wont use the underline and visited color any more.

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
a:hover{
    color:red;
}
div{
    background-color:#000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7rrruajb/1/

Hope this is what your looking for.

Comment: Thanks Gijs, this solved my problem .. when i use a instead of a:link , it worked, visited part doesnt work now. Thanks so much ..

Comment: @Vedat Be sure to mark this as an answer then if it solved your problem.

Comment: What do you mean with "i could do sth like this"? @Vedat

Answer (score 0):

```
a:visited{
   text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `a` instead of `a:link` - `a` applies to unvisited and visited link, `a:link` just unvisited ones.

Compare the two:

**`a:link`**

```css
a:link {
    color:red;
}

a:hover {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#666">
  <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank">hello</a>
</div>
```

**`a`**

```css
a {
    color:red;
}

a:hover {
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:#666">
  <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank">hello</a>
</div>
```